# xfs_repair -L sent all data to lost+found directory with code names

Tags: xfs

After a RAID recovery, my xfs partition of 20 TB did not mount and I tried to repair it with xfs_repair and subsequently xfs_repair -L option. Now the partition could be mounted and all the folders are there but no data is available inside those folders. Everything moved to lost+found. Is there a way to fetch the actual files from lost_found.

Answer (score 1):

`xfs_repair -L` discards the journal log and should be used only as a last resort effort because it *will* lead to data loss if the filesystem was in active use.

Having *all* files moved inside `lost+found` means that massive metadata corruption happened - probably due to some underlying RAID issue.

In such situations, one should recover from backups rather than relying on which files are inside `lost+found`

Answer (score -1):

I didn’t need to use L but also my files went to the lost and found seems like when a setup has more than one disk if critical inodes are cleared everything goes to the lost and found and you have to rebuild everything but you do have the data. For recognisable stuff it’s fairly easy but if the file names were corrupted and now they are hex you won’t be able to figure it out especially with 20tb.

Mine is only 6gb and I found a lot of the usr and people parts of the disk but root seems to be lost